# ZeroSSL Renew SSL Certification

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate, zerossl

So, my SSL certificate is about to be expired soon (in 2 weeks). I have just successfully issued a renew certificate yesterday, but when I check my website, it still shows the old certificate. Is there a way to just use the new certificate like maybe deleting the existing one? And if the existing certificate expired, does it automatically use the new one?

Here is the screenshot of my complete installation of the new certificate:
[Installation complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GKnp.png)

I followed the guide on how to renew the certificate based on this link: https://help.zerossl.com/hc/en-us/articles/360060119813-Renewing-an-SSL-Certificate

PS I'm using an IP address website, that's why I chose zeroSSL.

Tried contacting the zeroSSL team but no answers.

Comment: Maybe more information is helpful, like how you renew your certificate and what you used to host your website.

Comment: You need to install the new certificate the same way you did with the original certificate.

Comment: I've updated my question, please check @WinterCicada

Comment: I've followed the guide same as I did on my existing certificate and it successfully issued by zeroSSL but the certificate detail on my website is still using the old one @SteffenUllrich

Comment: The ZeroSSL guide only includes how to renew the certificate and get the new certificate, not how to install it. You have to install the new certificate the same way you install the old one.

Comment: I recommend you to use tools like [acme.sh](https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh) to help you manage your certificate, it can request a ZeroSSL certificate on your server and install it.

Comment: I've installed it to my server (I'm using nginx) as you can see on my updated question. It says that my installation is complete. But when I check on my website, it still uses the old certificate @WinterCicada

Comment: Did you check the certificate through a web browser? The web browser may cache the previous site, you can toggle the `Disable Cache` checkbox on the Network tab of the Web Developer Tools and refresh the page. This can force the browser to request the latest site and certificate. If that is not the case, I'm afraid I couldn't help. @jyra